# Assemble.GetType produces null although the type is in the assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, types, console

The next code produces null:

```
Type type = typeof(Console).Assembly.GetType("Console"); //null
```

How is that possible? I look for the type Console in the Assembly where Console is defined...

Answer (score 0):

`GetType()` expects the full name of the type, including the namespace.

If you want that single type, you can get it also using just `typeof(Console)`.

Comment: Is there no way to change that?

Comment: There may exist more types called Console in different namespaces, so in general, no.
You could however enumerate all of the types and find the ones with the matching name.

Comment: Like this typeof(Console).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == "Console")

Answer (score 0):

I think Tomas very clearly answers your question; however, I wanted to add that since you actually know the type you can do something similar to the following:

```
    Type type = typeof(Console);
    type = type.Assembly.GetType(type.FullName);
```

You can just use the FullName property to get the full name of the type including the namespace. This way in the future you can avoid the problem you just experienced.